# Differences between LINQ where and where method on a collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, where-clause

Is there any difference between using LinQ to filter compared to using a collections Where() method.

More specifically,

First

```
var numQuery = from num in numbers
               where (num % 2) == 0
               select num;
```

Second

```
var numQuery = numbers.Where(num => num % 2 == 0);
```

In the above query, which is better? And is there any performance consideration?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if your code gets optimised down but I would think that using "(num & 1) == 0" would be quicker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference. The first one is the `Query Type` LINQ. The second one is the `Extension Method` type. I'll prefer the second one because it has many built-in functionalities.

from the link below

> "...however there is no semantic difference between method syntax and query syntax."

**[MSDN: LINQ Query Syntax versus Method Syntax (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)**

Comment: Should be noted that the compiler turns query comprehension syntax into extension method calls.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no difference at all (just as John pointed out).

To convince anyone who is not willing to believe, I've checked what IL code is produced, and it is *exactly* the same (posted below for those being curious):

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.4    
IL_0002:  newarr      System.Int32
IL_0007:  dup         
IL_0008:  ldtoken     {A078DB01-D7BE-45F4-8D98-8D2FA673C282}.$$method0x6000001-1
IL_000D:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.InitializeArray
IL_0012:  stloc.0     
IL_0013:  ldloc.0     
IL_0014:  ldsfld      UserQuery.CS$9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
IL_0019:  brtrue.s    IL_002E
IL_001B:  ldnull      
IL_001C:  ldftn       b__0
IL_0022:  newobj      System.Func..ctor
IL_0027:  stsfld      UserQuery.CS$9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
IL_002C:  br.s        IL_002E
IL_002E:  ldsfld      UserQuery.CS$9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
IL_0033:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.Where
IL_0038:  stloc.1     
IL_0039:  ldloc.1     
IL_003A:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump

b__0:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0002:  rem         
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0004:  ceq         
IL_0006:  stloc.0     
IL_0007:  br.s        IL_0009
IL_0009:  ldloc.0     
IL_000A:  ret
```

Comment: @JohnWoo thanks :) I thought it may be one of the ways to convince people for 100% that it is the same :)

Comment: @JohnWoo I'm still fairly new here and trying to get how things work. Did you edit this post and add only a single space?

Comment: @MaciekTalaska: Its exactly the same because compiler converts query type to method type at compile time. Acc to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal and that is the whole point of making it obvious to everyone - is there any better proof than providing a IL code?

Comment: @MaciekTalaska: Can you help me in by telling from where do you produce this IL Code? I also want to do so.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal for such small code snippets I am using LinqPad (http://www.linqpad.net/) but you may also use one of the freely available .net decompilers: Telerik JustDecompile, JetBrains DotPeek, ILSpy (open source).

Answer (score 0):

using Where() extension method does not need the select part `Select(a => a)` if you return the instance of each entry.

Query type expression always need the select part `select a` at the end of the expression, which looks redundant but required by the syntax.

Moreover, First() extension method does not have a corresponding query type syntax. So 
you need to add brackets to query type expression (from a in b where a > 0 select a).First()
For nested query, you also need to add brackets to query type expression.
I can use `b.First(a > 0)` directly instead of `b.Where(a > 0).First()`

Therefore, I advocate using extension methods.